# webbrowser control on page load or refresh

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control on my Vb.net winform. Now i need to find a way to detect if the page reloads or refreshed.

Similar to `WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`.

**Example:**
`WebBrowser1_DocumentOnLoad`, **OR** `WebBrowser1_DocumentOnRefreshed`

Comment: Check out my answer, I think it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim wb as new webbrowser
wb.navigate(url)
do while wb.ReadyState <>  WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
application.doevents()
loop

wb.refresh()

do while wb.ReadyState <>  WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
application.doevents()
loop

msgbox("refreshed")
```

Comment: I think he is asking, he wants to know if a user refreshes the page, not how to do it himself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept the BeforeNavigate2 event, and if it is directed to the exact same URL that is currently loaded in the WB control (BN2 event provides a URL argument for you to read from and test, and your WB.LocationURL or WB.Document.URL can tell you the current URL of your WB control so you can compare it to.

So, when you intercept the BeforeNavigate2 event, you can do your comparison there, you can also do it during DocumentComplete, whatever you prefer. There is no OnRefresh event unfortunately (that I know of) so give my method a try and let me know how you get along with it, and if you need any further help.

Cheers.